# Событие по созданию div в body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Как можно отследить создание div по определённому классу в body, чтобы в дальнейшем работать с объектом div и его содержимым?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver Попробуйте использовать это. Там приведен пример, который позволит сделать правильный callback. Чтобы найти то, что изменился div (или добавился ), нужно смотреть на mutation.Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться относительно новым `HTML5 API` - [`MutationObserver`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

В этом примере мы слушаем все изменения в `<body>`, однако лучше слушать что-то менее изменяемое, например какой-то определенный вложенный блок, в котором вы ожидаете изменения

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(list => list.forEach(check));
document.body.onload = () => observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true});

function modify() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = Math.random();
  document.body.append(div);
}

function check(mutation){
    // в mutation.addedNodes лежит NodeList из добавленных узлов
    let el = mutation.addedNodes[0]; 
    console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="modify()">modify</button>
```

Если этот вариант не подходит по каким либо соображениям, можно воспользоваться старым способом - слушать событие `'DOMSubtreeModified'`, однако оно `deprecated` и иметь с ним дело - то еще удовольствие.